# Separating models, logic and DAOs in express/node.js

Tags: node.js, express

What's the best way to separate the different tiers of an express application, so that my app.js file doesn't get crammed full of functions?  I'm coming from a Java world, so I typically have my models, business logic and DAO code in separate tiers.

The other question, that has been bothering me: how do I open a connection to a DB in app.js and then share that among the various pieces of code that need access to it?  Not the routed functions, but the business logic modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this project as separate files as follows:

https://github.com/lethus/popbroker

routes.js - Here we put the routes, usually referenced to controllers

models.js - Model here you put the functions of MongoDB

forms.js - You work the validation of objects

controllers / users.js - That would be something like java UI, here we call the models.js and do the insert, update, list, Finds

Comment: It's a good separation, but I'd love to see an example using an actual database, to see how a connection pool can best be utilized.

Comment: Take a look at Christian's Express-js blog as another example https://github.com/csanz/expressjs-blog

Comment: Link above is broken. Here's the new location: https://github.com/csanz/nodejs-blog